# Eating enough carbohydrates to build muscle

Tags: weightlifting, nutrition, protein, carbohydrate, muscle-recovery

There is an issue I always surpressed my mind of: the necessary carbohydrates per day.

One thing I learned a while ago is the importance of consuming at least 20 gram of protein per 3-4 hours in order to build muscle.

Consuming enough protein seems to be very easy to me, when I can't have a real meal I just take Whey Protein and I know I have enough protein in the body for the next 3-4 hours.

How much carbohydrates I need is what I am always guessing. My guessing is to get as much as carbohydrates as I can as long I don't feel like I ate too much. Each time I take Whey Protein, I drink a cup of milk with 5 spoons of oatmeal (just from the box without boiling it). Sometimes I also add some whole rice (4-5 spoons) and sometimes just a banana/yogurt.

In the evening, after a workout I take Whey Protein then I shower and 30 minutes later I consume 2 whole bread, eggs and cottage cheese.

Is it enough? Is consuming Whey Protein and Oat Meal mostly enough? What can I do better?

EDIT:

I'm 26 years old, my height is 1.83cm and my bodyweight is 90kg.

Comment: To be honest, you could eat as little as 50g of carbs per day. Its a bit extreme, but a ketogenic diet has its upsides. Check the eating academy for some info on the low carb diet.

Comment: Visit this site for future nutrition related questions:  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44550/nutrition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike protein and fat, there are no specific requirements for your body with respect to carbs. This is why people are able to get away with ketogenic diets that cut out all carbs. That being said, carbs definitely serve a purpose, especially with regard to physical fitness, muscle growth, and sports.

Carbs are the preferred fuel source for your body, and thus it is preferential to have a reserve of carbs to fuel your activities. By doing so, you allow your body to perform optimally, which will allow you to thereby increase workout intensity and as a result build more muscle mass (whether this is by a significant factor, I do not know).

Depending on your volume of activity, I would suggest anywhere from 2 grams of carbs per pound of bodyweight, all the way up to 8+ grams per pound (extremely active). If you are moderately active, 2-4 grams/pound would be the range I would stick with.

Some further reading:

- http://www.eatright.org/Public/content.aspx?id=11633
- http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/healthy-diet/NU00200

Comment: Thank you very much! you helped me a lot to shed some light on the carbs consumption.

Answer (score 1):

According to the primal movement, 150g of carbs a day is sufficient for someone living an active lifestyle. Going beyond that will lead to weight gain.

Ofcourse, make sure they're complex carbs, preferably derived from fruits and nuts.

> 100-150 grams/day – Primal Blueprint Maintenance Range
>
> This range based on body weight and activity level. When combined with Primal exercises, allows for genetically optimal fat burning and muscle development. Range derived from Grok’s (ancestors’) example of enjoying abundant vegetables and fruits and avoiding grains and sugars.

Read more: http://www.marksdailyapple.com/the-primal-carbohydrate-continuum/#ixzz2ZMwyTGGI