# Coingestion of carbohydrate and protein before/during/after a weightlifting session: how much carbohydrate?

Tags: weightlifting, nutrition, protein

I read on {1}:

> It has been established that the **ingestion of carbohydrate and protein** before (13,14) and/or after exercise (5,10,11,13–15) inhibits protein breakdown and stimulates muscle protein synthesis, resulting in net muscle protein accretion during recovery.

and {2}:

[image]

I know that the protein intake should be around 25g immediately after exercise. How much carbohydrate am I supposed to eat before/during/after a weightlifting session when coingested with proteins to optimize  muscle protein synthesis and recovery?

I am aware of the Stack Exchange question [Eating enough carbohydrates to build muscle](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/11998/3806) but it doesn't focus on the coingestion of carbohydrate and protein.

---

References:

- {1} Beelen, Milou, Michael Tieland, Annemie P. Gijsen, Hanne Vandereyt, Arie K. Kies, Harm Kuipers, Wim HM Saris, René Koopman, and Luc JC van Loon. "Coingestion of carbohydrate and protein hydrolysate stimulates muscle protein synthesis during exercise in young men, with no further increase during subsequent overnight recovery." The Journal of nutrition 138, no. 11 (2008): 2198-2204. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14076123771562292313&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22; http://jn.nutrition.org/content/138/11/2198.full  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430005107/http://jn.nutrition.org/content/138/11/2198.full))
- {2} Van Loon, L. J. "Protein ingestion prior to sleep: Potential for optimizing post-exercise recovery." Sports Science Exchange 26, no. 117 (2013): 1-5. http://www.gssiweb.org/Article/sse-117-protein-ingestion-prior-to-sleep-potential-for-optimizing-post-exercise-recovery  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170115135007/http://www.gssiweb.org/Article/sse-117-protein-ingestion-prior-to-sleep-potential-for-optimizing-post-exercise-recovery))

Answer (score 1):

From the last paragraph of {1}:

> Even more so than with protein, carbohydrate dosage
>   and timing relative to resistance training is a gray area
>   lacking cohesive data to form concrete recommendations.
>   It is tempting to recommend pre- and postexercise
>   carbohydrate doses that at least match or
>   exceed the amounts of protein consumed in these meals.
>   However, carbohydrate availability during and after exercise
>   is of greater concern for endurance as opposed to
>   strength or hypertrophy goals. Furthermore, the importance
>   of co-ingesting post-exercise protein and carbohydrate
>   has recently been challenged by studies examining
>   the early recovery period, particularly when sufficient protein is provided. Koopman et al [52] found that after
>   full-body resistance training, adding carbohydrate (0.15,
>   or 0.6 g/kg/hr) to amply dosed casein hydrolysate (0.3 g/
>   kg/hr) did not increase whole body protein balance during
>   a 6-hour post-exercise recovery period compared to
>   the protein-only treatment. Subsequently, Staples et al
>   [53] reported that after lower-body resistance exercise
>   (leg extensions), the increase in post-exercise muscle
>   protein balance from ingesting 25 g whey isolate was not
>   improved by an additional 50 g maltodextrin during a 3-
>   hour recovery period. For the goal of maximizing rates
>   of muscle gain, these findings support the broader objective
>   of meeting total daily carbohydrate need instead
>   of specifically timing its constituent doses. Collectively,
>   these data indicate an increased potential for dietary
>   flexibility while maintaining the pursuit of optimal
>   timing.

---

References:

- {1} Aragon, Alan Albert, and Brad Jon Schoenfeld. "Nutrient timing revisited: is there a post-exercise anabolic window?." Journal of the international society of sports nutrition 10, no. 1 (2013): 5. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15105262524877299902&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; https://doi.org/10.1186/1550-2783-10-5

Comment: Can you summarise? Just adding a quote from text isn't a great answer.