# Coingestion of carbohydrate and protein before/during/after a weightlifting session: what type of carbohydrate?

Tags: weightlifting, nutrition, protein

I read on {1}:

> It has been established that the **ingestion of carbohydrate and protein** before (13,14) and/or after exercise (5,10,11,13–15) inhibits protein breakdown and stimulates muscle protein synthesis, resulting in net muscle protein accretion during recovery.

and {2}:

[image]

Are there some specific [types of carbohydrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Carbohydrate&oldid=777926424#Division) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170501020452/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbohydrate#Division)) that I am supposed to eat before/during/after a weightlifting session when coingested with proteins to optimize  muscle protein synthesis and recovery?

I am aware of the Stack Exchange question [Eating enough carbohydrates to build muscle](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/11998/3806) but it doesn't focus on the coingestion of carbohydrate and protein.

---

References:

- {1} Beelen, Milou, Michael Tieland, Annemie P. Gijsen, Hanne Vandereyt, Arie K. Kies, Harm Kuipers, Wim HM Saris, René Koopman, and Luc JC van Loon. "Coingestion of carbohydrate and protein hydrolysate stimulates muscle protein synthesis during exercise in young men, with no further increase during subsequent overnight recovery." The Journal of nutrition 138, no. 11 (2008): 2198-2204. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14076123771562292313&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22; http://jn.nutrition.org/content/138/11/2198.full  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430005107/http://jn.nutrition.org/content/138/11/2198.full))
- {2} Van Loon, L. J. "Protein ingestion prior to sleep: Potential for optimizing post-exercise recovery." Sports Science Exchange 26, no. 117 (2013): 1-5. http://www.gssiweb.org/Article/sse-117-protein-ingestion-prior-to-sleep-potential-for-optimizing-post-exercise-recovery  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170115135007/http://www.gssiweb.org/Article/sse-117-protein-ingestion-prior-to-sleep-potential-for-optimizing-post-exercise-recovery))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Coingestion of carbohydrate and protein before/during/after a weightlifting session: how much carbohydrate?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/33984/coingestion-of-carbohydrate-and-protein-before-during-after-a-weightlifting-sess)

Comment: @rrirower the question you linked to asked about the quantity of carbohydrate, whereas this question asked about the type of carbohydrate